# Display year in comment lock post notice tooltip if lock expires in a later calendar year

Tags: feature-request, tooltips, post-notices, comment-lock

I recently came across [a post that had its comments disabled for a very long period of time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389149/2157772). According to the notice, the lock won't expire until 3,623 days from now.

However, when I mouse over the number of days to see which day it will be unlocked on, it only mentions "Mar 9". As the lock is long enough, it's completely unclear *when* exactly it will unlock, as the year is not shown.

Can we please make it so that if a lock isn't slated to expire within the current calendar year, it will show the year in the tooltip?